# JAXB unmarshal XML elements to object wrapper

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying unmarshal XML to object with wrapped elements.

**XML looks:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encding="utf-8"?>
<Output xmlns="_xxx_" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Companies>
      <Company>
         ...
      </Company>
      <Company>
         ...
      </Company>
      ...
   </Companies>
   <People>
      <Person>
         ...
      </Person>
      <Person>
         ...
      </Person>
      ...
   </People>
   <Relations>
      <Relation>
         ...
      </Relation>
      <Relation>
         ...
      </Relation>
      ...
   </Relations>
   <Info ... />
</Output>
```

I would like to have Compenies, People and Relations in Lists. I try this code, but it doesn't work:

**Java Code**

*Ouput*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Output", namespace = "_xxx_")
@XmlType(propOrder={"companies", "people", "relations", "info"})
public class Output {

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Companies")
   @XmlElement(name = "Company" type = Company.class)
   private List<Company> companies;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "People")
   @XmlElement(name = "Person", type = Person.class)
   private List<Person> people;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Relations")
   @XmlElement(name = "Relation", type = Relation.class)
   private List<Relation> relations;

   @XmlElement(name = "Info")
   private Info info;

   public Output() {
      this.companies = new ArrayList<>();
      this.people = new ArrayList<>();
      this.relations = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public List<Company> getCompanies() {
       return companies;
   }

   public void setCompanies(List<Company> companies) {
       this.companies = companies;
   }

   public List<Person> getPeople() {
       return people;
   }

   public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
       this.people = people;
   }

   public List<Relation> getRelations() {
       return relations;
   }

   public void setRelations(List<Relation> relations) {
       this.relations = relations;
   }

   public Info getInfo() {
       return info;
   }

   public void setInfo(Info info) {
       this.info = info;
   } 
}
```

And for example *Company* looks (other classes are similar)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Company")
public class Company {
   ...
}
```

If I use this it creates empty Lists, but, if I change code to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Output", namespace = "_xxx_")
@XmlType(propOrder={"companies", "people", "relations", "info"})
public class Output {
   @XmlElement(name = "Companies")
   private Companies companies;

   @XmlElement(name = "People")
   private People people;
   ....

   public Companies getCompanies() {
       return companies;
   }

   public void setCompanies(Companies companies) {
       this.companies = companies;
   }

   ...
}
```

where *Companies* class looks:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Companies")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Companies {

   @XmlElement(name = "Company")
   private List<Company> companies;

   public List<Company> getCompanies() {
       return companies;
   }

   public void setCompanies(List<Company> companies) {
       this.companies = companies;
   }
}
```

it works fine, but it isn't nice solution.

Can anyone advise me what is wrong here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the instructions on this [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html). I use mapping to java.util.Map.